# Errors creating constraint trigger

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Let me start by saying that I’m a Linux/Unix admin. That being said my manager has tasked me with moving older PostgreSQL databases to a RedHat server running 8.4.20.  I was successful moving a 7.2.1 db but I’m running into issues moving a 7.4.20 db.

I use `pg_dump –c filename` and `psql < filename`. For the problematic db everything runs until I get to a `CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER` statement. If I run it as it is in the file I get :

> NOTICE:  ignoring incomplete trigger group for constraint "" FOREIGN KEY data(ups) REFERENCES upsinfo(ups)
>   DETAIL:  Found referenced table's DELETE trigger.
>   CREATE TRIGGER

If I run `set schema 'pg_catalog';` I get:

> ERROR:  relation "upsinfo" does not exist

The tables (I think) involved are:

```
CREATE TABLE upsinfo (
    ups text NOT NULL,
    ipaddr inet,
    rcomm text,
    wcomm text,
    reachable boolean,
    managed boolean,
    comments text,
    region text
);

CREATE TABLE data (
    date timestamp with time zone,
    ups text,
    mib text,
    value text
);
```

The trigger problem trigger statement:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT TRIGGER "<unnamed>"
    AFTER DELETE ON upsinfo
    FROM data
    NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE "RI_FKey_cascade_del"('<unnamed>', 'data', 'upsinfo', 'UNSPECIFIED', 'ups', 'ups');
```

I know that the `RI_FKey_cascade_del` function is defined differently in the different versions of pg_catalog. Note that search_path is set to ‘public, pg_catalog’ so I’m also confused why I have to set the schema.

Again I’m not a real PostgreSQL DBA so try to be kind.

Answer (score 0):

Oof, those are *really* old postgres versions, including the version you're upgrading to (8.4 was released in 2009, and support ended in 2014).

**The short answer** is that, as long as `upsinfo` and `data` are being created and populated, you're probably fine, and good to go. But one of your foreign key relationships is broken.

**The long answer**, well, let me see if I can explain what is going on (or, at least, what I think is going on).

I'm guessing that the original table definition of `data` included something like `FOREIGN KEY (ups) REFERENCES upsinfo (ups) ON DELETE CASCADE`. That causes postgres to automatically make some trigger constraints: 1- every time there's a new row for `data`, make sure that its `ups` column matches an existing row in `upsinfo`, and 2- every time you delete a row from `upsinfo`, delete the corresponding rows in `data`, based on the matching `ups` value.

That (not very informative) error message can come up when the foreign key relationship doesn't work. In order for a foreign key to make sense, the referenced value needs to be unique -- there should be only one row in `upsinfo` for each distinct value of `ups`. In order for postgres to *know* that, there needs to be a unique index or primary key on `upsinfo.ups`.

In this case, one of a couple things could be breaking it:

1. There's no primary key or unique index on `upsinfo.ups` (postgres should not have allowed a foreign key, but may have in very old versions)
2. There used to be a unique index, but it hadn't properly enforced uniqueness, so it didn't get successfully imported (a bug, again likely from a very old version)

In either case, if that foreign key relationship is important, you can try to fix it once the import is complete. Start by trying to make a unique index on `upsinfo.ups`, and see if you have problems. If you do, resolve the duplicate entries, and try again till it works. Then issue something like:

```
ALTER TABLE data
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (ups) REFERENCES upsinfo (ups) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Of course, if things are working, it's possible you don't need to fix the foreign key, in which case you're probably able to ignore those errors and just move forward.

Hope that helps, and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a part of ON DELETE CONSTRAINT. If I were you I would delete all such statements and replace them with a proper constraint definition on the target table.

Table definition should then look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE bookings (
    boo_id serial NOT NULL,
    boo_hotelid character varying NOT NULL,
    boo_roomid integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_bookings
        PRIMARY KEY (boo_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_bookings_boo_roomid 
        FOREIGN KEY (boo_roomid)
        REFERENCES rooms (roo_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
) WITHOUT OIDS;
```

And this part is what will internally create the trigger:

```
    CONSTRAINT fk_bookings_boo_roomid 
        FOREIGN KEY (boo_roomid)
        REFERENCES rooms (roo_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But, to be honest, I do not have an understanding for an upgrade to an unsupported version. You know the Postgres is version 9.5 now, right?

Comment: Thanks for you help. (And for being gentle.) It's the typical story: No one maintains software for years and then get all wound up all of a sudden. I'm going to ask (more like beg) to update the Postgres version on the new server.